# seleccionar y subir elemento de una lista tipo SELECT a la primera posición JavaScript y HTML

Tags: javascript, html

*Requiero mover u cambiar la posición cualquier elemento seleccionado dentro de una lista de tipo SELECT con un botón , estoy tratando de modificar u complementar una función similar que ocupe para mover de izquierda a derecha pero no logro obtenerla, agradecería su ayuda*

```js
function moveToup(){
        var e = document.getElementById("ListaA");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        var oOption = document.createElement("option");
        oOption.text = strUser;
        oOption.value = strUser;

        e.options.up(e.selectedIndex);
        PersistState();
    }
```

```html
<select name="orden" id="ListaA" size="10">
    <option value="1">Texto 1</option>
    <option value="2">Texto 2</option>
    <option value="3">Texto 3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Suvir" id="btntoup" name="btnToup" onclick="moveToup();"><br />
<input type="button" value="bajar" />
```

Comment: `moveToup`... ¿debería suBir el elemento seleccionado una posición arriba desde el lugar en que está, o arriba del todo? Por ejemplo, ¿Texto 3 subiría a la seguna, o a la primera posición?

Comment: seria el elemento que elijas suba una  poción arriba, desplazando hacia abajo la que le sigue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) resulta útil en este caso, la cual inserta (*mueve*, si es necesario) un elemento dentro de un padre y antes de un hijo.

```js
function moveToUp() {
    var e = document.getElementById("ListaA");

    // se ha seleccionado una única opción y no es la primera
    if (e.selectedOptions.length === 1 && e.selectedIndex > 0) {
        e.insertBefore(e.selectedOptions[0], e.options[e.selectedIndex - 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok muchas gracias, lo implementare para observar el resultado.

Answer (score 0):

No recuerdo haber visto un método nativo para intercambiar posiciones en arreglos, por lo que te recomiendo hacerlo de forma manual:

1. Analiza si hay un elemento seleccionado y que no sea el primero, no tiene sentido tratar de moverlo si ya está arriba
2. "Respalda" los datos (valor y texto) de la posición que va a ocupar
3. Actualiza el elemento superior con los datos del seleccionado
4. Usa los datos respaldados para aplicar al elemento actual
5. Finalmente, no es obligatorio, pero se recomienda que el elemento movido siga marcado como seleccionado para mejorar la experiencia del usuario

```js
function moveToup(){
    let e = document.getElementById("ListaA");
    if(e.selectedIndex <= 0) {
        // No modificar si ya está arriba o no se ha seleccionado algo
        return;
    }
    // Elemento superior
    let up = e.options[e.selectedIndex - 1];
    // Elemento actual
    let current = e.options[e.selectedIndex]
    // Guardar valor y texto de elemento de arriba
    let upValue = up.value;
    let upText = up.text;
    // Mover valores de elemento seleccionado a arriba
    up.value = current.value;
    up.text = current.text;
    // Renovar valores de elemento actual
    current.value = upValue;
    current.text = upText;
    // "Mantener" elemento seleccionado
    e.selectedIndex = e.selectedIndex - 1;

    // La siguiente función no existe, comentada para evitar error
    // PersistState();
}
```

```html
<select name="orden" id="ListaA" size="10">
    <option value="1">Texto 1</option>
    <option value="2">Texto 2</option>
    <option value="3">Texto 3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Suvir" id="btntoup" name="btnToup" onclick="moveToup();"><br />
<input type="button" value="bajar" />
```

Comment: Excelente gracias, yo lo intente implementar en array ya que no me quedaba de esta forma..